# How to create solr core with CQL driver in DSE?

Tags: solr

In our data initialization model, we will check if the table exists and create the table if not. However, solr core will need to be created out of the product with dsetool or curl. Is there a way to create the core if the table is created?

Answer (score 0):

No till now their is no API provided by Solr or any third party to create a core , we have to depend on the dsetool or curl method .

Even if you drop your table then your solr core is automatically dropped and need to be rebuild again when table is recreated .